# Get store message size per destination on demand for ActiveMQ

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, kahadb

Is there a way to get store message size per destination on demand for ActiveMQ using some command line tool?

I am using ActiveMQ 5.14.4 with kahadb as persistent store. I am using multi kahadb support to split kahadb for destinations with high persistent use cases. All other destination are using common kaahdb and its size is growing. So I was wondering if there is a tool to get store usage per destination so that I can take an informed decision to break my kahadb further.

P.S.: I can't break kahadb for all destination and then take an estimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using activemq's command line utilities. Here is the reference of command line utilty: http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-command-line-tools-reference.html

You need to view name and StoreMEssageSize mbeans using query and provide appropriate broker's jmx url

> activemq query --view Name,StoreMessageSize --jmxurl service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://remotehost:1099/jmxrmi